# How to create an autosys job that runs on a weekend only at X hours

Tags: unix, automation, autosys, jil

I need to create an autosys job that run on Saturday and Sunday only at Noon and 11:00 p.m. CST
below is the script that I wrote based on what I saw online.

I'm new to this , can someone else please check and confirm if there's any other thing that I'm missing that can cause some issue?

> insert_job: name   job_type: CMD
>
> command: /directory/zzz/xxx.ksh /directory/xxx/xxx
>
> machine: ZZZ
>
> owner: user
>
> permission:
>
> date_conditions: 1
>
> days_of_week: sa,su
>
> start_mins: 5,20,35,50
>
> run_window: "12:00 , 23:00"
>
> condition: s(XXX_XXX_CONTROL)
>
> description: "pull xxx files"
>
> std_out_file: $dummy.out
>
> std_err_file: $dummy.err
>
> alarm_if_fail: 1
>
> profile: /directory/directory.profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your block for determining which days your jobs will run looks correct:

```
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: sa,su
```

But your block for determining when on those days your job runs is off:

```
start_mins: 5,20,35,50 # specifies how many minutes after the top of an hour a job starts
run_window: "12:00 , 23:00"
```

As your JIL is now, the job will run 4 times an hour for 11 hours:

> 12:05, 12:20, 12:35, 12:50, 13:05, 13:20, ..., 22:35, and 22:50

You most likely want specific **start_times**:

```
start_times: "12:00, 23:00"
```

**start_times** and **start_mins** can't be defined in the same JIL, and **run_window** would be extraneous here, so it can be omitted along with **start_mins**.

You can also take a look at the **must_start_times** attribute if you want an alarm if your jobs didn't start on time.